# SetSystemCursor with cursor resource

Tags: vb.net

I want to know if it's possible to load a cursor from `My.Resources` with `SetSystemCursor`.

My code:

```
Private Declare Function SetSystemCursor Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hCursor As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Function LoadCursorFromFile Lib "user32.dll" Alias "LoadCursorFromFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As IntPtr
Private Const IDC_ARROW As UInt32 = 32512
Dim SavedCursor As Icon

...

SetSystemCursor(My.Ressources.CustomCursor, IDC_ARROW)
```

Comment: Have you tried your code?  Errors?  Results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd just like to point out that the second parameter of `SetSystemCursor()` should be a `UInteger`, not `Integer`:

```
Private Declare Function SetSystemCursor Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hCursor As IntPtr, ByVal id As UInteger) As Boolean
```

However these days you should rather declare P/Invokes with the [**`DllImport` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal hCursor As IntPtr, ByVal id As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
```

---

**EDIT:**

I stumbled upon [**this blog post**](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-to-load-an-embedded-cursor-from-resources-in-c-windows-forms/) which provided a pretty neat way of loading 32-bit depth cursors from a byte array.

I've converted it to VB.NET and fixed the data type of some unmanaged functions, and it appears to work perfectly! It can load 32-bit cursors without a problem and you can use them just like you would with any other cursor.

I renamed the class to `CursorHelper` for it to have a more generic name as I implemented some of the methods from my previous class in it as well.

*Credit to [Jerome Viveiros](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/) for the original code!*

```
'+--------------------------------------------+'
'|                                            |'
'|             == CursorHelper ==             |'
'|                                            |'
'| Original name:       CursorResourceLoader  |'
'| Original creator:    Jerome Viveiros       |'
'|                                            |'
'| VB.NET conversion:   Visual Vincent        |'
'| Misc. additions:     Visual Vincent        |'
'|                                            |'
'+--------------------------------------------+'

'Original code from:
'https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-to-load-an-embedded-cursor-from-resources-in-c-windows-forms/

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public NotInheritable Class CursorHelper
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

#Region "Methods"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a cursor from an array of bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cursorResource">The byte array to create the cursor from (must be data in a cursor format!).</param>
    ''' <param name="ImageIndex">The index of the image to use as a cursor (usually cursors only have one image, so leave this at 0).</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function LoadEmbeddedCursor(ByVal cursorResource As Byte(), Optional ByVal ImageIndex As Integer = 0) As Cursor
        Dim ResourceHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(cursorResource, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Dim IconImage As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim CursorHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

        Try
            Dim Header As IconHeader = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(ResourceHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), GetType(IconHeader)), IconHeader)

            If ImageIndex >= Header.count Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(ImageIndex)
            End If

            Dim IconInfoPtr As IntPtr = ResourceHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(IconHeader)) + ImageIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(IconInfo))
            Dim Info As IconInfo = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(IconInfoPtr, GetType(IconInfo)), IconInfo)

            IconImage = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Info.size + 4)
            Marshal.WriteInt16(IconImage + 0, Info.hotspot_x)
            Marshal.WriteInt16(IconImage + 2, Info.hotspot_y)
            Marshal.Copy(cursorResource, Info.offset, IconImage + 4, Info.size)

            CursorHandle = NativeMethods.CreateIconFromResource(IconImage, Info.size + 4, False, &H30000)
            Return New Cursor(CursorHandle)

        Finally
            If CursorHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                NativeMethods.DestroyIcon(CursorHandle)
            End If

            If IconImage <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IconImage)
            End If

            If ResourceHandle.IsAllocated Then
                ResourceHandle.Free()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a cursor from an array of bytes and sets it to be the specified system cursor.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Bytes">The array of bytes to create the cursor from.</param>
    ''' <param name="Type">The system cursor to assign the new cursor to.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal Bytes As Byte(), ByVal Type As SystemCursor) As Boolean
        Using Cursor As Cursor = CursorHelper.LoadEmbeddedCursor(Bytes)
            Return CursorHelper.SetSystemCursor(Cursor, Type)
        End Using
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets a cursor to be the specified system cursor.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Handle">The handle of the new cursor.</param>
    ''' <param name="Type">The system cursor to assign the new cursor to.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Type As SystemCursor) As Boolean
        Return NativeMethods.SetSystemCursor(Handle, CType(Type, UInteger))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets a cursor to be the specified system cursor.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Cursor">The new cursor.</param>
    ''' <param name="Type">The system cursor to assign the new cursor to.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal Cursor As Cursor, ByVal Type As SystemCursor) As Boolean
        Return NativeMethods.SetSystemCursor(Cursor.Handle, CType(Type, UInteger))
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Enumerations"
    Public Enum SystemCursor As UInteger
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Standard arrow and small hourglass
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_APPSTARTING = 32650

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Standard arrow
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_NORMAL = 32512

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Crosshair
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_CROSS = 32515

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Hand
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_HAND = 32649

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Arrow and question mark
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_HELP = 32651

        ''' <summary>
        ''' I-beam
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_IBEAM = 32513

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Slashed circle
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_NO = 32648

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Four-pointed arrow pointing north, south, east, and west
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_SIZEALL = 32646

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Double-pointed arrow pointing northeast and southwest
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_SIZENESW = 32643

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Double-pointed arrow pointing north and south
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_SIZENS = 32645

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Double-pointed arrow pointing northwest and southeast
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_SIZENWSE = 32642

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Double-pointed arrow pointing west and east
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_SIZEWE = 32644

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Vertical arrow
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_UP = 32516

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Hourglass
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        OCR_WAIT = 32514
    End Enum
#End Region

#Region "Native Methods"
    Private NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
        Public Shared Function DestroyIcon(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
        Public Shared Function CreateIconFromResource(ByVal presbits As IntPtr, ByVal dwResSize As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fIcon As Boolean, ByVal dwVer As UInteger) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal hCursor As IntPtr, ByVal id As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function
    End Class
#End Region

#Region "Native Structures"
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack:=1)> _
    Private Structure IconHeader
        <FieldOffset(0)> _
        Public reserved As Short

        <FieldOffset(2)> _
        Public type As Short

        <FieldOffset(4)> _
        Public count As Short
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack:=1)> _
    Private Structure IconInfo
        <FieldOffset(0)> _
        Public width As Byte

        <FieldOffset(1)> _
        Public height As Byte

        <FieldOffset(2)> _
        Public colors As Byte

        <FieldOffset(3)> _
        Public reserved As Byte

        <FieldOffset(4)> _
        Public planes As Short

        <FieldOffset(6)> _
        Public bpp As Short

        <FieldOffset(4)> _
        Public hotspot_x As Short

        <FieldOffset(6)> _
        Public hotspot_y As Short

        <FieldOffset(8)> _
        Public size As Integer

        <FieldOffset(12)> _
        Public offset As Integer
    End Structure

#End Region

End Class
```

**Example usage:**

```
CursorHelper.SetSystemCursor(My.Resources.CustomCursor, CursorHelper.SystemCursor.OCR_NORMAL)
```

Comment: I have a little problem the cursor become all black. But if i put it in windows it not full black otherwise it working.

Comment: @Jni : Does the same thing happen if you load the cursor from a file using `LoadCursorFromFile()`?

Comment: I dont know it was not working with LoadCursorFile if you dont know it not problem i was just want to know if you have an idea.

Comment: @Jni : Actually I do... I just remembered that the .NET `Cursor` class has got some troubles with colored cursors (the one I tested with was black and white). It's rather late here so I'll have to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, Thanks so much

Comment: ... I forgot to say my cursor is white and black.

Comment: @Jni : Well, it's got issues with 32-bit color cursors. Anyhow I should still try to find an all-round solution for future users.