# VB 2015: Custom cursor appears to be black

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cursor

I had the idea, to use in October a custom wait cursor as an easteregg. This code works, but when the cursor is shown, it is black (the original .Cur file is in color, the resource pumpkin says everything).

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my function to create a random cursor:

```
Private Function getcursor() As Cursor
    If Date.Now.Month <> 10 Then Return Cursors.WaitCursor
    If Date.Now.Day < 15 Then Return Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Select Case rnd.Next(0, 2)
        Case 0
            'Return New Cursor(New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.pumpkin))
            Return New Cursor(New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.pumpkin))
        Case 1
            Return New Cursor(New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.pumpkin2))
        Case 2
            Return New Cursor(New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.pumpkin3))
        Case Else
            Return Cursors.WaitCursor
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: How did you create the cursor file?

Comment: Downloaded free .cur files from the web.

Comment: I seached the whole day... after posting this question, I found out a solution that works: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/369025-proper-way-to-use-a-custom-cursor/page__st__15

Comment: Alternate solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515523/3740093